# Django cannot pass the value form to the constructor

Tags: python, django

I have tried everything, but I cannot pass the value form to the constructor of ContactCSVModel below:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ConfiguratorForm(data=request.POST)

    # Try and import CSV
    ContactCSVModel.import_data(data=file, form=form)
```

the the class...

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel, form):

    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    company = CharField()
    mobile = CharField()
    group = DjangoModelField(Group)
    contact_owner = DjangoModelField(User)
```

that CsvModel is part of Django-adaptors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel, form):` means that the `ContactCSVModel` extends a class called `form`. I think this is what you really intended:

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):
    # stüfe
    def __init__(self, form):
        # using the form for other stüfe.
        # maybe self.form = form?
```

Comment: I see, so how can I just pass form into the class?

Comment: Well, that entirely depends on your goal and what is in ContactCSVModel.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, what about passing it here ContactCSVModel.import_data(data=file, form=form)

Comment: import_data() got an unexpected keyword argument 'form'

Comment: Ahh, That is because you are adding the `form` argument on the `init` method, not `import_data`...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is use the `form` to pass data to the `ContactCSVModel` and `ConfiguratorForm` has the same fields? If so, you should make the form into a `ModelForm`

```
class ConfiguratorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactCSVModel
```

Otherwise, I am completely lost with what you are attempting to do...

For example, what is currently in `ConfiguratorForm` and where did `file` come from?